# Как добавить CSS в iframe c другим доменом?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

Необходимо изменить дизайн стороннего сайта (добавить CSS) , сохранив функционал, на стороне клиента. Можно ли это сделать c помощью iframe и jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя: [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 1):

Во фрейме нельзя, с помощью jquery можно [cross-domain-ajax](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/).

Comment: какое это имеет отношение к вопросу?

Comment: загружать сторонний сайт не в iframe, а в DOM. Решение позволяет делать кроссдоменный аякс-запрос.

Answer (score 1):

@sergiks Странно. Stack Overflow так не считает.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960406/add-css-to-iframe
Только вот с динамическими ID у фреймов проблемы возникнут (например виджеты от соц. сетей.)

Comment: 1. Читаем в общем про Same Origin Policy.
2. Смотрим на EDIT про S.O.P. в упомянутом треде на SO.
3. ... ?
4. Profit!